# Como obtener el Id del RecyclerView seleccionado C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, recyclerview

Tengo un evento `OnClick` en Xamarin.Android que se gatilla cada vez que selecciono uno de los resultados en un `RecyclerView` (CardView), el problema es que tengo 3 RecyclerViews gatillados todos con el mismo OnClick, y quería saber si hay una manera simple y sencilla de obtener el nombre o algún identificador unico del Recyclerview en el que esta el CardView seleccionado? Tal vez algo tipo: **RecyclerViewClients1**.

No tengo idea de como intentarlo.

```
 public void OnClick(int position)
        {                                         
                VarGlobal.gIdRecyclerMaterial = (position);                 

                Context context = Application.Context;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(cMaterial));
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);            
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

De hecho precisamente es la posición, la cual puedes obtener mediante la variable `position`, recuerda que el primer elemento inicia con el indice 0:

```
public void OnClick(int position)
        {               
         ...
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Click RecyclerViewClients: " + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();

         ...
        }
```

Comment: Tal vez no me explique bien. Esa seria la posición o Id del CardView seleccionado (digamos que tengo 10 elementos en el RecyclerView), pero no del RecyclerView (tengo 3 RecyclerViews con 10 elementos cada uno). Y yo necesito identificar el Recyclerview.